# What is the meaning of "against one's disposition"?

Tags: grammar

What does this mean?

> Against my disposition, I chuckled in front of the president.

Comment: So this  man is not one to chukle in front of anyone by nature?

Comment: Yes, *to chuckle* at everyone is **not** that person's nature.

Comment: At least he didn't _upchuck_ in front of the president... :) oh wait, that's what Bush the Elder did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disposition describes someones general behaviour or inhibitions.  His disposition in this regard is to be very prim and proper when in the company of VIPs.  But, for whatever reason, something made him forget his traditional behaviour so he laughed.

Comment: An alternate phrasing: "I am generally not disposed to chuckling, but I did in front of the president," meaning "Most of the time I don't chuckle, but this time I did".